# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 1]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

this is what I did. The code is down bellow. I have the music.csv dataset.
The error is Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 1]. The error details is after the code.

```py
# importing Data 
import pandas as pd

music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
music_data
# split into training and testing- nothing to clean
# genre = predictions
# Inputs are age and gender and output is genre
# method=drop
X = music_data.drop(columns=['genre'])  # has everything but genre
# X= INPUT
Y = music_data['genre']  # only genre
# Y=OUTPUT
# now select algorithm
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()  # model
model.fit(X, Y)
prediction = model.predict([[21, 1]])
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)  # 20% of date=testing
# first two input other output
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

score = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
```

Then this error comes. This error is a value error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_28312/3992581865.py in <module>
      5 model.fit(X_train, y_train)
      6 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
----> 7 score = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)

c:\users\shrey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
 61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
 62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
 64 
 65             # extra_args > 0

c:\users\shrey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-        
packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, 
sample_weight)
200 
201     # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
--> 202     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
203     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
204     if y_type.startswith('multilabel'):

c:\users\shrey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
 81     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
 82     """
 ---> 83     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
 84     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
 85     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

 c:\users\shrey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
317     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
318     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 319         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
320                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
321 

 ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 1]
```

Pls help me. I dont know whats happening but I think it has to do with this score = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the test data after splitting, you have four entries (rows), which means y_test has a  length of 4.

While trying to predict on [21, 1] you are basically predicting on just one row. So, prediction has length of 1.

That's why you get an inconsistent number of samples error.

You can navigate this by

1. predicting on X_test

   ```
   prediction = model.predict(X_test)
   ```
2. In case you want to predict on a new data, you have to separate the targets(y_test) and the input features (X_test)
   and then make predictions
   For eg. if target for [21,1] is [2]

   ```
   prediction = model.predict([[21,1]])
   y_test = [2] ## note this depends on what the corresponding target label is
   score = accuracy_score(y_test,prediction)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your predictions variable after train test splitting

````
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```
````